# Fetch issues of responses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, typescript, react-native

I don't understand why that happens and the response gives: `{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}` i really don't get it any help?

```
export const handleConnectivityChange = async() => {
let probablyHasInternet;
try {
    const googleCall = await fetch(
        'https://google.com', {
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
            Pragma: 'no-cache',
            Expires: 0,
        },
    })
    probablyHasInternet = googleCall.status === 200;
    console.log(probablyHasInternet)
} catch (e) {
    probablyHasInternet = false;
}
return probablyHasInternet
```

}

Comment: Try this -->>` const response = await googleCall.json();
    console.log('Response', response);`

Comment: nothing happen it's not a json response